# Composing an HTML view with conditional logic

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, aurelia, durandal, durandal-2.0

In my multitenant app, I have many instances of the following:

```
<!-- ko if: tenantA() -->
<div>Tenant One snippet</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: tenantB() -->
<div>Tenant Two snippet</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: userTypeA() -->
<div>User type A snippet</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: userTypeB() -->
<div>User type B snippet</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is an oversimplified example but you get the picture - many components of a larger view are composed based on business logic from various data points.

The benefit of this is that I have one view and the solution footprint is more manageable, but it is a bit messy.  What alternative patterns are there?

I was considering splitting anything and everything that is displayed on condition into an html template and rendering html based on logic in the js viewmodel, but this introduces more complexity into my viewmodels and muddles up my solution footprint (this is important to me for quick navigation during dev).

I am working with durandal and knockout but tagged `Aurelia` because I will be migrating sometime and think this is more of a pattern question than a particular technology question.

Comment: Are the conditions exclusive?

Answer (score 3):

**Logical Pattern, Software Design Concepts**

You definitely want to be thinking in terms of [components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering), regardless of what language or framework you choose to use for implementation.

1. Divide up your application into different views (perhaps one for each of the navigation menu elements).
2. Subdivide each of these views further (as needed) based on what types of functions they serve.  I like the way that Bootstrap's panels help you visualize this.
3. Develop each of these components and give them names, like ContactList, ContactEdit, ContactView, etc.  Develop HTML views and JavaScript, TypeScript or other language viewmodels for each of these components.  Be sure to use [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) logic to separate your views from the data, using placeholders in the view to indicate where you will fill in the data.  The views are like templates.
4. Use your specific language or framework to link it all together.

Here is a great tutorial on [Component-Based Software Architecture and Design](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_architecture_design/component_based_architecture.htm).

**Aurelia Component Logic**

I'm currently using Aurelia, and since you mentioned it, we'll use the Aurelia framework as an example to illustrate the above principles.  Best practice would be to create the components (for modularity and reuse) and then use the `if.bind` property to include them or not in the DOM.

Example:

```
<tenant-one if.bind="tenantA"></tenant-one>
<tenant-two if.bind="tenantB"></tenant-two>
```

Or to only show/hide each component from the view (but include all in the DOM), you would use `show.bind` instead of `if.bind`, but that seems to make less sense for your use case.

**Aurelia Data Binding**

Since I don't know what you actually hope to display here, the above code is based on your code snippet in the question.  However, for similar views where only the data will change (like a template), you would bind the data from the parent to the child so that it can be displayed correctly.  In Aurelia, this would look like this.

Example:

```
<tenant-view data.bind="tenantData"></tenant-view>
```

More Complex Example:

```
<tenant-view fname.bind="firstName" lname.bind="lastName" data.bind="tenantData"></tenant-view>
```

In each of these examples, you would need to develop 4 files.  You would need the main (parent) container that has a view and a viewmodel.  The viewmodel would be in charge of retrieving or accessing the tenant information and then passing it on to each of the child components.  The child component would have its own view and viewmodel.

For example, the TenantView view (highly simplified) might be like this:

```
<template>
  <p><strong>Tenant Name: </strong>${fname} ${lname}</p>
  <p><strong>Additional Data: </strong>${data}</p>
  <p if.bind="data.rentDue">Tenant's rent is due!</p>
</template>
```

And then the TenantView viewmodel (again, highly simplified) might be like this:

```
import { bindable, bindingMode } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class TenantView {
  @bindable fname;
  @bindable lname;
  @bindable data;
}
```

Once you have this component created, you would then insert it (optionally) in the parent view, like this:

```
<template>
  <h1>Contact View</h1>
  <h2>${firstName} ${lastName}</h2>

  <tenant-view if.bind="cat == 'tenant'" fname.bind="firstName" lname.bind="lastName" data.bind="contactData"></tenant-view>

  <phone-numbers data.bind="contactData"></phone-numbers> <!-- another component -->

  <page-footer></page-footer> <!-- another component -->

</template>
```

Comment: This is nice, but it's a technology-specific solution.  I'd like to abstract this into a "pattern definition" type of answer as I believe that would be more valuable for future readers.  You are recommending extracting the view components into separate files and then leaving the view logic in the view, right?

Comment: My only issue with this is that I have hundreds of instances of this - where the view depends on some condition.  Extracting these out into individual files will be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Your views should contain the appropriate logic to adapt to the diversity of needs, without necessarily requiring different view files for each one. You would only display different view files if there is significant difference of purpose or structure.  I assume you already know how to bind parent-child properties.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a broader view of component logic in software architecture and design, as well as additional examples of implementation in Aurelia.  Using components allows each view to have its own logic as needed.

Comment: Cool - +1.  As an aside, would you say that Aurelia is at an adequate state of maturity to support a large consumer-facing application?  Last I checked it was in a state of flux as the conventions were getting ironed out (~1y ago).  Looks like I can't award bounty for another day.

Answer (score 1):

HTML templates always tend to become messy and difficult to maintain once your app starts to grow big.

I would suggest you to break your HTML into multiple components there by It will be easier to maintain and most important you will end up reusing all these components.

one of the greatest example would be JSX which works best with React.js where in you can write HTML inside JS. so you can divide your app into maintainable components. give JSX a try it really makes your life lot easier as font-end developer.

Comment: In Aurelia it would be easy. Best practice would be to create the components (for modularity and reuse) and then use the `if.bind` property to include them or not in the DOM.